# What should I do about unstable packages in Visual Studio 2017, error: was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of target framework

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I'm using Visual Studio to make an app. It works on Android and I'm trying to get it to work on iOS, but I need to resolve this unstable package in my dependencies.
Any advice about what I should do?

[image: Here is the issue the I have.]

Error Message:

> Package 'OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms 1.1.0-unstable0011' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework'.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: What is the actual package that's unstable?

Comment: And what do you mean by "unstable"?

Comment: If you click on the link above I posted a picture of my issue.

Comment: If I click on the link above I get a message saying imgur is blocked on work computers. Post the actual error message.

Comment: If I click an imgur link, it gets logged by corporate.  Please include the *text* of the error in the question.  Bonus: your error message can be indexed by search engines, making your question more useful to others!

Comment: I'm removing the C# tag, as this affects any language in VS capable of using Nuget packages, and the answer also does not depend on the language.  I added the Nuget tag instead.

Comment: I posted the error message that I have. Hope that helps.

Comment: You've said "unstable" multiple times, but it appears you just made that up. There's nothing here indicating anything is unstable.

Comment: The error says 'OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms 1.1.0-unstable001' which led me to think it was unstable.

Comment: `1.1.0-unstable001` is a [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/#spec-item-9) standard way of indicating a pre-release version that is not considered production-ready by the developers / project managers.  That's all.  It doesn't actually have anything to do with your issue: the package isn't available for your target framework.  Go to the Nuget settings for your project and uncheck "Include prereleases" if you want to only use production-ready packages.  I don't think that will fix your problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a warning message, not an error message, and this is by design.

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks for target framework information.

.NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 4.6.1 have a huge surface area overlap. 
For this Visual Studio and NuGet have added the concept of a fallback framework, where when a user tries to install a .NET Standard package in a .NET Framework project, it will allow the installation but warn the user that it's not 100% compatible and that there may be certain cases in which this does not work.

Related
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5192
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Enable-.NET-Core-2.0-projects-to-work-with-.NET-Framework-4.6.1-compatible-packages